# how to find the root elements name using xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, mule

Hi am having an XML file I have to find the root element of it using xpath am using mule ESB so I need to set this root element as variable so anyone can provide me xpath for finding the name of the root element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper MEL expression is `#[xpath('xpath:name(/*)')]`

The other answers helped me to find the proper answer.Thanks all

Answer (score 6):

This should work.

`name(/*)`

**sample XML**

```
<the>
    <element>hello</element>
</the>
```

**Result**

```
the
```

Answer (score 4):

in mule you can define the MEL expression as

`#[xpath:name(/*)]`

to retrieve the root element

Comment: Its was not working but i found the answer with the help of your answer thank you

Answer (score 3):

Since xpath was deprecated, xpath3 should be used instead.

Mel example: `#[xpath3('name(/*)')]`